# Python - calculation of surplus

Tags: python

I am trying to develop an application to calculate the surplus value on the IRPJ. It consists of, if the value of the IRPJ is greater than 60k, calculate 10% over the excess of 60k, but I am not able to put the second value as a variable, it gives the following error:

```
l_calcirpj = Label(calc, text='O valor a ser pago de IRPJ é de: {:.2f}'.format(irpj2))
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'irpj2' referenced before assignment
```

Follow the code below:

```
from tkinter import *
# ---
calc = Tk()
calc.title('mikaelson')
calc.geometry('350x350')
# ---
l_receita = Label(text='Receita')
l_receita.place(x=15, y=15)
e_receita = Entry(calc)
e_receita.place(x=100, y=15)
# ---
def calcular():

    receita = float(e_receita.get())
    # ---
    irpj = receita * 32 / 100
    if irpj > 60000:
        irpj2 = (irpj - 60000) * 10 / 100
    else:
        print('menor que 60k')

    l_calcirpj = Label(calc, text='O valor a ser pago de IRPJ é de: {:.2f}'.format(irpj2))
    l_calcirpj.place(x=15, y=60)
    # ---
    e_receita.delete(0, END)

bt = Button(calc, text='Calcular', command=calcular)
bt.place(x=15, y=95)


calc.mainloop()
```

Comment: If irpj <= 60000 you don't set irpj2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `irpj2` is only created if `irpj>60000`.  Try creating the variable and initialising it to a sensible default (e.g. 0) outside of the `if` statement.